# How do you find emails sent per day with ExactTarget API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am looking for an overview of what API(s), endpoint(s) and objects I need to learn, in order to generate this report for my client's ExactTarget account (approximately 4M email addresses):

```
Date        | Emails Sent
-------------------------------
2015-01-01  | 123456
2015-01-02  | 102030
2015-01-03  | 120288
```

How to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Send object can be used to retrieve summary tracking information for sends to lists or data extensions (not Triggered sends).  This is accessible in the SOAP API.

Example SOAP using the retrieve method.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-8ffdcfea-db23-48f9-9d1c-f8178caa70ba-1">
            <o:Username>ccc</o:Username>
            <o:Password>ccc</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
            <Properties>SentDate</Properties>
            <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>SendDate</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
               <DateValue>2009-06-29T00:00:00</DateValue>
               <DateValue>2009-06-30T00:00:00</DateValue>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This uses a filter which will get all of the sends for a single day, the results will need to be iterated through to look at the NumberSent so it can be summed to get the total for the day.